# Is there a 64 bit version of boost::hash_value

Tags: boost, hash-function

As it looks [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp) boost::hash_value always returns a size_t value.

Does boost have a 64 bit hash function as well?

Comment: On my system (Mac OS X 10.8, with clang), the following code:
`std::cout << sizeof ( size_t ) << std::endl;`  prints "8"

Comment: But this isn't something you can count on, is it? See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t#stddef.h)

Comment: No. It isn't. all the `hash` stuff that I know of return a `size_t` (`boost::hash` and `std::hash`).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not sure I quite understood your answer. Are you saying that the boost library doesn't offer a hash function that always returns a 54 bit variable?

Comment: @Subway `size_t` is platform-dependent, and there's no platform-independent `hash_value`.

Comment: @IgorR What do you mean by "there's no platform-independent hash_value"?

Comment: @Subway `hash_value` returns 32bit result on 32bit platform, and 64bit result on 64bit platform.

Comment: Thanks. MarshallClow & Igor, either of you can put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it, if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the hash routines that I know of (both `boost::hash` and `std::hash1` in `C++11`) hash things to a `size_t` value.

The representation of `size_t` (like `int`) varies from platform to platform.

The answer to your question in the general case is no - there is no 64-bit version of `boost::hash_value`.

If you are running on a platform where `size_t` is a 64 bit quantity (say, `x86_64`) then yes, `boost::hash_value` will be 64 bits.